# What is difference class library and razor class library?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to know What is difference.

class library vs razor class library

Comment: Razor Class Library provides a way to package and distribute UI components to be referenced and reused within a host application. As [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) mentioned , `Razor views, pages, controllers, page models, Razor components, View components, and data models can be built into a Razor class library (RCL).` but normally these views, pages etc UI related functioning part would not be included in generic class library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Razor Class Library is use specifically for creating a set of reusable User Interface widgets that you can plug-in to multiple web apps

A Class Library is a set of usually non UI related classes, to implement a particular function/service or api.   e.g. Most of the .Net libraries we use are class libraries.